# Reset array internal pointer to the beginning of the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is this needed in JavaScript in any context? For example I am trying to copy an array and for some reason when I loop through it and copy the values over one by one the resulting array is missing one value; the only thing I can think of why this is so is because the array I am looping over isn't starting at the beginning.

So, is there a way to reset the internal pointer of an array in JavaScript?

Comment: In a word... "No". There is no concept of an "internal array pointer" in JavaScript, like there is in PHP. Could you perhaps add a [MCVE] to your question demonstrating the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Post your code, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: perhaps there is other reason why you miss one value... perhaps its empty/null/misconfigured/unknown type ?

Comment: *"I am trying to copy an array ..."*. [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice]).

Comment: I'm not at the PC that I have the code on at the moment and hence why I didn't post up my copy method; I could easily write it up again but I feel that wouldn't be of use unless I could also post an example of the structure of the input array and the resulting array. I will do this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myArray = ["aa", "bb"];
var myArray2 = [];
for (var i=0,  tot=myArray.length; i < tot; i++) {
   myArray2.push(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's similar to how I was doing it, save the variable setting on each iteration.

Comment: I think it'll help if you can post your code Whenever you can.